Spring integration leak
I have a spring integration application. It basically has a gateway with its requestChannel, and a @ServiceActivator that consumes from the channel. The @ServiceActivator uses a poller to fetch new messages from the channel.
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10", maxMessagesPerPoll = "50", taskExecutor = "myExecutor"))

<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="1" rejection-policy="DISCARD"/>

When I run the application, I've seen that lots of java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$Node, org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$$Lambda and org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$$Lambda are being created and never released.

In fact, I've seen that these object are being created without the need to add new messages in the queue, so it looks like the poller creates all these objects. Which I can confirm because when I disable the @ServiceActivator, these objects are not created.
Could someone please suggest how to get rid off these objects?
Thanks in advance!

The behavior is expected.
The QueueChannel does not have subscribers. Instead it is polled periodically.
That is done by the mentioned poller configuration and TaskScheduler internally. Since this poller has no knowledge that messages have been producer to queue or not, there is no way to control its behavior. The polling task has to be scheduled anyway: no messages in the queue - OK, give up and move on.
The problem is really here: fixedDelay = "10". That means start a new polling after 10 milliseconds from the finish of the previous one.
So, consider to adjust that fixedDelay = "10" to something more meaningful and less stressful.
